# ORACLE - return record by comparing foreign key to each of the returned key

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a SQL statement which returns the "single-row subquery returns more than one row" error in Oracle:

```
SELECT * FROM lds_placement 
WHERE fk1_account_id = 
  (SELECT lds_account.account_id 
   FROM lds_account 
   WHERE lds_account.fk1_consultant_id = 
     (SELECT consultant_id 
      FROM lds_consultant 
      WHERE UPPER(cst_name) LIKE UPPER(:app_user) || ' %' ));
```

How can I compare and display all records from lds_placement where the fk1_account_id is equal to either one of the returned account_id from lds_account table?

Comment: Not knowing your data, my guess is that you want your two equality conditions to be `IN` instead (i.e. `fk1_account_id IN (<<query>>)`).  Though I would suspect that you really just want to join the three tables instead.

Comment: yes, using IN worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a sub-query can return a set (of values) as opposed to a single (scalar) value, you cannot use `=`. Have you tried using `IN` instead?

(To elaborate: what would `something = (1,2,3)` mean... one or all of them? It seems you want `something is one of (1,2,3)`, which in SQL is `something IN (1,2,3)` -- to wit, replace `=` with `IN` in your query and you should be good to go.)

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped.

Comment: Subquery problems can always be solved with an easy 3-step process: 1) What do I think this subquery returns? 2) What does it actually return? 3) What do I expect the server to do with it?